# How to refer to the human being?

Tags: meaning-in-context, personal-pronouns

Is it ok to refer to the human kind or the human being with "it"?
Ex. The human being is responsible of its destiny or should it be their destiny?

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use "it" to refer to a person?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116983/can-i-use-it-to-refer-to-a-person)

Comment: Depends on if you want to sound like a creepy anti-human scientist type that says the vastness of the universe makes human beings irrelevant, or not.

Comment: @TheDoc The linked question is similar, but not exactly the same. I've referenced it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no, [you don't use **it** to refer to human beings](http://www.englishgrammar.org/impersonal-pronoun/), only to refer to objects (with a couple of rare exceptions [mentioned in this similar post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116983/can-i-use-it-to-refer-to-a-person)).

> The human being is responsible of its destiny or should it be their destiny?

First of all, I'd recommend **for** not **of**.

Secondly, are you talking about *all of humanity* ("**Humanity** is responsible..."), or are you talking about a *single individual human* ("**Each** human being is responsible...")? The meaning is quite different.

Regarding the pronoun, English has no gender-neutral singular pronoun (other than *it*, which we've already excluded), so you have a few options, none of them perfect:

1. Pick a gender for your pronouns and hope that people understand you mean to include everyone, regardless of gender. *Each human being is responsible for **his** own destiny*. Historically, this was very common (especially using the masculine), but this has fallen out of style, and is viewed by some as sexist.
2. Use both pronouns (*his or her*), or a compound form (his/her, s/he). *Each human being is responsible for **his or her** own destiny.* In my opinion, this is the preferred option.
3. Use the plural in place of a singular. *Each human being is responsible for **their** own destiny*. This is common, but frowned upon by many.
4. Use of a [non-traditional pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns#Preferred_pronouns) like '**ze**' or '**hir**'. You see this especially within the LGBTQ community, and is usually *self-referencing* by those who identify outside the gender binary. No single set of alternate pronouns has caught on, though, and none are likely to be widely understood.

There are other options, like using "one" in place of the pronoun, but that doesn't really work in your sentence.

In your case I would recommend

> Each human being is responsible for his or her own destiny.

Some references:

- [Oxford Dictionaries: 'He or she' vs 'they'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/he-or-she-versus-they)
- [Canada Translation Portal: Gender-Neutral Writing: The Pronoun Problem](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/pep/index-eng.html?lang=eng&page=usage_6_gender_neutral_writing_pronoun_problem)

Comment: You said "one" wouldn't work. What about "Each human being is responsible for one's destiny." Would this be wrong?

Comment: @Moritz Hmm, still doesn't sound quite right to my ears, you more often hear it with  "one" in both parts of the sentence, like "One must be responsible for one's own destiny".